# setVisibility only works once on ImageView

Tags: android, gridview, view, imageview

I am trying to make views in a GridView become invisible and visible. I can make it work the first time I call INVISIBLE AND VISIBLE but subsequent attempts don't work.

```
  private void flashImageSeq(){
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 9){
        animate(i);         
        ++i;
    }
}

private void startThread() {
  t = new Thread() {
    public void run () {
       try {
        sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
  };

  t.start();
}

private void animate(int position){
    gridview.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
  // imgView is defined in View getView for Adapter code not shown
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView)gridview.getChildAt(position);
    imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
  startThread();
  imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
}
```

the second call to flashImageSeq() doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try

```
private void flashImageSeq(){
int i = 0;
while (i < 9){
    animate(i);         
    ++i;
}
}

private void startThread(final ImageView im) {
  t = new Thread() {
    public void run () {
       try {
        sleep(500);
        yourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

            im.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
  };

  t.start();
}

private void animate(int position){
    gridview.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
  // imgView is defined in View getView for Adapter code not shown
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView)gridview.getChildAt(position);
    imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
  startThread();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new thread that sleeps for 500 ms but your two setVisibility calls happen within one split millisecond.

You should use `Thread.sleep(500)` to actually pause the mainthread BUT this is really BAD practice!

Better create a Thread that runs the loop and make sure the setVisi calls are executed with "runOnUIThread" as the other answer shows it